# Solar panel to charge 9 volts batteries, but need to power 120 volts pump

Tags: batteries, amplifier, solar-cell

I am making a very simple circuit that takes charges 9 volt batteries from 18 volts solar panels. Then, there is an interrupter to let the the batteries power a water pump that requires 120volts. How can I transform 9 volts of the batteries into 120 volts? I can not find anything online about that.

Comment: You need an inverter - but they are usually intended to be run from 12 volt lead-acid (or similar) batteries.  Are you using the common small rectangular 9 volt batteries?  How much power does your 120 volt pump require?

Comment: There's not enough information here. Do you have any specifications for this water pump?

Comment: Only requires 110-120volts at 60hz and 4watts.

Comment: problems with pumps is the peak/avg ratio can be high e.g. <10:1 which then places a heavy load during the actuator peak thrust and this can kill the source voltage in a step-up converter with impedance ratios being the square of the peak voltage ratio.

Comment: The best way is to replace the pump with one that works at the right voltage. They aren't expensive.

Answer (score 0):

There are small inverters that plug into an auto cigarette lighter outlet. They look like an oversized USB adapter. One of those will provide 120 volts AC from 12 volts DC. It will not be very efficient and the motor may overheat due to the poor waveform, but it will probably be ok for a short time. You will probably need 8 C or D cells.

At 4 watts, the motor must be something like a small aquarium filter pump motor. The motor is very inefficient, so the stalled current won't be much higher than the normal running current.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I used.

LINK:  [4 Watt 12VDC Pump $10](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00KL1JWZC)

[image]

LINK: [Inexpensive Lead Acid Batteries 2 FOR $33 14 Ah, free shipping with Prime](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B007ROUQ6U)

[image]